# tbb concurrent hash maps: how to compare and set

Tags: concurrency, hashmap, tbb

I need to update the contents in concurrent_hash_map provided by TBB in a CAS fashion. That is, if a key is already present, I look at the value corresponding to the key and update the value in an atomic operation (and if the value changes meanwhile due to another thread doing the same thing, my operation should fail).

In other words, I provide an "expected value" to the insert method and it updates the value only if the current value matches the expected value.

Is there a to achieve this in concurrent_hash_map of TBB?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given types Key and T, the following code achieves the goal, assuming that type T is a type for which tbb::atomic is supported.

```
class AtomicValue {
    mutable tbb::atomic<T> content;
public:
    AtomicValue() {}
    AtomicValue( T value ) {content=value;}
    bool cas( T value, T comparand ) const {
        return content.compare_and_swap(value,comparand)==comparand;
    }
};

typedef tbb::concurrent_hash_map<Key,AtomicValue> table;

bool update( table& x, Key key, T value, T comparand ) {
    table::const_accessor a;
    if( !x.insert(a,table::value_type(key,value) ) ) {
        // value is already there
        return a->second.cas(value,comparand);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The tricky part is using a const_accessor to do the update.  Using a regular accessor would serialize the updates.  But a const_accessor allows multiple threads to access the same table entry at the same time.  It's called a "const_accessor" because the usual use case involves reading the value.  But here the code uses CAS to arbitrate updates.  The wrapper class "AtomicValue" enables doing CAS on a const object.

A similar solution should work for tbb::concurrent_unordered_map, which might be better if non-blocking is the key criterion, because concurrent_unordered_map has a non-blocking implementation.

Better yet, if you have the latest TBB **and** a compiler that supports the C++11 features of constexpr and defaulted/deleted member functions, the following should work:

```
 typedef tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<Key,tbb::atomic<T> > table;

bool update( table& x, Key key, T value, T comparand ) {
    auto p = x.insert(table::value_type(key,value) );
    if( !p.second ) {
        // value is already there
        return p.first->second.compare_and_swap(value,comparand) == comparand;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It worked for me with gcc 4.7 when compiled with "g++ -std=c++0x".

Comment: What if the table is resized / rehashed between a failed insert and the following CAS? Wouldn't the updated value be written to an invalid memory location?

Comment: concurrent_unordered_map uses a split-order list, not open addressing.  So resizing does not move an item.  See http://people.csail.mit.edu/shanir/publications/Split-Ordered_Lists.pdf for details on split-order lists -- they are a clever idea.